# C#: get row back in datagridview (shift+tab)

Tags: c#, indexing, datagridview, tabs

I programmatically jump to the next row by pressing the tab button.
If i want do jump back, i use the tab + shift key. 
If tab + shift is pressed, the rowcount gets reduced by two.
When I want to go back from the last row, the index jumps to the first control, which has the tab index of 0.
Whats the problem at the last row?

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
        {
            int row = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            row++;
            if (row > dataGridView1.RowCount - 1)
            {
                menuStrip1.Select();
                datensatzToolStripMenuItem.Select();
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[0, 0];
            }
            else dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[0, row];
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Shift && e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
        {
            int row = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            row -= 2;
            if (row < 0) 
            {
                menuStrip1.Select();
                datensatzToolStripMenuItem.Select();
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[0, 0];
            }
            else dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[0, row];
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Two things: Firstly, I didn't think Tab keys are captured by the KeyDown event. And secondly, if SHIFT+Tab is pressed, both conditions in that method will be met - i.e. both (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab) and (e.Modifiers == Keys.Shift && e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab) will be true.

Comment: My problem is, that the standard tab assignment jumps to the next cell, but I need to jump to the next row, therefore i programmed it with the keydown event.

Comment: Have you tested whether the Tab key actually triggers the KeyDown event?

Comment: Yes, works fine. But when i press shift + tab in the last row in the dgv, it focuses the first row and selects the first control (tab index 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is because both conditions in your code will be met when SHIFT+Tab is pressed.

The following code works fine on my machine.

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab) {
        if (e.Modifiers != Keys.Shift) {
            int row = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            row++;
            if (row > dataGridView1.RowCount - 1) {
                menuStrip1.Select();
                datensatzToolStripMenuItem.Select();
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[0, 0];
            }
            else {
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[0, row];
            }
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else {
            int row = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            row -= 1;
            if (row < 0) {
                menuStrip1.Select();
                datensatzToolStripMenuItem.Select();
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[0, 0];
            }
            else {
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[0, row];
            }
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```